# how do i resovle the TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Am coding a chatbot, a section of the codes print this  error

input_size = data['Input_size']
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

I need help to resolve this.

This is the code:

```py
with open('intents.json', 'r') as f:
    intents = json.load(f)

    FILE = "data.pth"
    data = torch.load

    input_size = data['Input_size']
    hidden_size = data["hidden_size"]
    output_size = data["output_size"]
    all_words = data["all_words"]
    tags = data["tags"]
    model_state = data["model_state"]
```

Error Message:

```
input_size = data['Input_size']
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: the error message is very clear, **data is a function**, because you don't want that (possible typo) look at the line that assigns `data` and see why it might be a function and fix it

Comment: Why are you creating `intents` if it is not being used? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The line that assigns data is this FILE = "data.pth"
    data = torch.load

Comment: i cant see the error

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually loading the data. Pass the filename to `torch.load()`:

```py
data = torch.load(FILE)
```

Then you will be able to access it by subscript (i.e. square brackets).

Comment: when i change the format i  get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @AnsahGodfred in which line do you get a syntax error? did you change anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The indentation isn't allright and you forgot to pass the argument to `torch.load` (load expects the data path) :

```py
with open('intents.json', 'r') as f:
    intents = json.load(f)

FILE = "data.pth"
data = torch.load(FILE)

input_size = data['Input_size']
...
```